# Installing Mysql gem on Ruby on Rails Windows 7 64x

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have been scouring the interweb for an answer, and none of the solutions have helped. I've seen nothing but dated info regarding this. In short I just started trying to teach myself how to use Ruby on Rails and I've been stuck for going on 6 hours just trying to install the mysql gem. This is what happens when I try

```
C:\Users\user>gem install mysql
Temporarily enhancing PATH to include DevKit...
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing mysql:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

C:/Ruby200-x64/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb
 checking for main() in -llibmysql... no
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
 libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
     --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=C:/Ruby200-x64/bin/ruby
    --with-mysql-dir
    --without-mysql-dir
    --with-mysql-include
    --without-mysql-include=${mysql-dir}/include
    --with-mysql-lib
    --without-mysql-lib=${mysql-dir}/
    --with-libmysqllib
    --without-libmysqllib


 Gem files will remain installed in C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/mysql
  -2.9.1 for inspection.
Results logged to C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/mysql-2.9.1/ext/mysql_
api/gem_make.out
```

Now, I've tried redirecting the path by using the opt and everything I'm stuck but optimistic. I heard RoR on 64x was a hassle but I'm sticking it out. Thanks for any help!

Comment: Save yourself the headache. Develop on Linux through a virtual machine. That's also essential experience for when you deploy your application to a server which will surely be Linux, not OS X or Windows.

Comment: that might actually be the best thing to do. Because I think I've wasted my day just trying to get the thing running.

Comment: No, don't need to develop on Linux. We use Windows & whilst it can be difficult, it's just as flexible as Linux

Comment: Nobody said you need to develop on Linux, but you are in a minority developing Rails on Windows, and, as such, will have a hard time finding support. Not just that, being familiar with Linux is essential come deployment, and so why not give yourself a head start?

Answer (score 0):

You ran the `gem` command so are you really trying to install MySQL or are you trying to install the *mysql gem*, which is a Ruby library that can talk to a MySQL database?

If you want to install the *mysql gem*, you should probably look into the mysql2 gem instead; that seems to be what everyone is using these days.  I would also recommend editing the question to make it clear that you are trying to install the *mysql gem* and not MySQL itself.

If you want to install *MySQL* (the database itself), please note that it is not a gem and so it cannot be installed with the `gem` command.  You will need to find installation instructions for Windows from [MySQL.com](http://www.mysql.com).

I think that most Rails developers use Linux or Mac OS X so developing in Windows can be a headache.  I would recommend that you make an Ubuntu (or some other flavor of Linux that you are familiar with) virtual machine using VirtualBox and do your Rails development inside the virtual machine.

Comment: I will check that out, I'll also change the wording of the question. I tried using 'gem install mysql2' aswell and it was basically the same error. I think I may just have to go through a virtual machine and I'm sure that will be another beast of its own.

Comment: *can't reword the question but hopefully people will catch on sorry for the gaffe

Answer (score 0):

**MYSQL2**

Firstly, I'd highly recommend using the [`mysql2`](https://rubygems.org/gems/mysql2) gem - it gives you colours & generally runs faster than the standard `mysql` gem.

Unfortunately, installing either on Windows has its troubles - mainly because *Windows doesn't have the MYSQL header files installed* by default.

---

**Fix**

We've written a tutorial about this [here](https://medium.com/p/a028f44d87f3)

Essentially, you have to do the following:

> 1. Install the MYSQL C-Connector headers locally (no spaces)
> 2. Install the MYSQL2 gem with correct references
> 3. Copy libmysql.dll from your MYSQL C-Connector folder to ruby folder

You need first download the **32 bit** version of MYSQL C-Connector:

[image]

This allows you to install the relevant header files for the MYSQL gem, which is mostly why the `gem` fails to install. You must install this **without any spaces in the path**.

Secondly, you then need to install the gem referencing the MYSQL C-Connector path:

```
gem install mysql2 --platform=ruby -- '--with-mysql-dir="C:\mysql-connector-path"'
```

This *should* install the gem for you. If it does, copy `libmysql.dll` from your MYSQL C-Connector `bin` folder & paste into your Ruby `bin` folder:

[image]

Comment: This was didn't work either still same issues. I installed in to c: and referenced it and it still came up with the issue.